# Ler um arquivo TXT e colocar seu conteúdo em uma LinkedList

Tags: java, lista, txt

Eu preciso ler um arquivo TXT e adicionar o seu conteúdo a variáveis de uma lista. Porém, o arquivo não tem a mesma quantidade de caracteres em todas as linhas. Na entrada possuímos uma sequência, de dois números em uma linha e uma sequência de caracteres em outra.

Exemplo de entrada:

```
2 1
ADEEDAE
3 2
AEAEDDA
1 4
AADDEAD
```

Meu objetivo é colocar 2 em uma variável, 1 em outra, `ADEEDAE` em outra e por aí vai.

Quando leio o arquivo eu acabo colocando tudo na posição 0 da lista e estou com dificuldades na hora de atribuir valores.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Código:

```
public static List<String[]> read(String file){
    List<String[]> data = new LinkedList<String[]>();
    String dataRow;

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while((dataRow = br.readLine())!=null) {
        String[] dataRecords = dataRow.split(" ");
        data.add(dataRecords);
        }       
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't find the File.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't read the line of the File.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Depois, para imprimir variáveis eu uso:

```
for(String[] robot : actionsToExecute) {
    System.out.println(robot[0]);
    System.out.println(robot[1]);
    System.out.println(robot[2]);
}
```

A ideia era usar o `for` para atribuir os valores:

```
    for(String[] robot : actionsToExecute) {
    String var1 = robot[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa. Além disso, se você está usando um for não faz sentido escolher a posição do vetor estaticamente.

Comment: Simplifiquei a pergunta. @GiulianaBezerra Deixa eu tentar explicar o que eu quis tentar fazer, como temos uma linked list a posição 0 na primeira iteração do for teria um valor diferente da iteração 0 da segunda iteração. xD é isso mesmo? ex: na primeira iteração um teria 2 na outra o 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu faria o seguinte:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charsets.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Mundo {

    private final int largura;
    private final int altura;
    private final List<Comando> comandos;

    public static Mundo read(String file) throws IOException {
        return new Mundo(Files
                .readAllLines​(new File(file).toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    public Mundo(List<String> linhas) {
        if (linhas.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.comandos = new ArrayList<>(100);
        boolean primeiro = true;
        int w = 0;
        int h = 0;
        for (String linha : linhas) {
            if (primeiro) {
                String[] partes = linha.split(" ");
                if (partes.length != 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                w = Integer.parseInt(partes[0]);
                h = Integer.parseInt(partes[1]);
                primeiro = false;
            } else {
                interpretarLinha(linha);
            }
        }
        this.largura = w;
        this.altura = h;
        return comandos;
    }

    private void interpretarLinha(String linha) {
        String[] partes = linha.split(" ");
        if (partes.length == 1) {
            interpretarSequencia(linha);
        } else if (partes.length == 2) {
            ComandoPosicionar cp = ComandoPosicionar.interpretar(linha);
            comandos.add(cp);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    private void interpretarSequencia(List<String> linhas) {
        for (char c : linha.toCharArray()) {
            Comando co = identificar(String.valueOf(c));
            comandos.add(co);
        }
    }

    private Comando identificar(char c) {
        if (c == 'R') return new ComandoR();
        if (c == 'M') return new ComandoM();
        if (c == 'L') return new ComandoL();
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    public void interpretar() {
        for (Comando c : comandos) {
            c.interpretar(this);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public interface Comando {
    public void interpretar(Mundo m);
}
```

```
public class ComandoR implements Comando {
    @Override
    public void interpretar(Mundo m) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
public class ComandoL implements Comando {
    @Override
    public void interpretar(Mundo m) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
public class ComandoM implements Comando {
    @Override
    public void interpretar(Mundo m) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
public class ComandoPosicionar implements Comando {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public static ComandoPosicionar interpretar(String linha) {
        String[] partes = linha.split(" ");
        int px = Integer.parseInt(partes[0]);
        int py = Integer.parseInt(partes[1]);
        return new LinhaNumerica(py, py);
    }

    private ComandoPosicionar(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public void interpretar(Mundo m) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Nesse código, a classe `Mundo` representa o seu mundo, contendo uma largura, uma altura e uma sequência de comandos que ele compila. A primeira linha do arquivo tem tratamento especial. As demais linhas podem ser numéricas ou textuais e representam sequências de comandos, elas são separadas pelo método `interpretarLinha` da classe `Mundo`.

A linha numérica corresponde a um comando com dois números que indicam uma posição.

A linha textual corresponde a uma sequência de comandos, onde cada comando corresponde a um caractere `M`, `L` ou `R` e o método `interpretarSequencia` de `Mundo` é a responsável por separá-los e o método `identificar` por saber quem é quem.

Na interface `Comando`, há um método que diz como ele deve ser interpretado, com todas as implementações da interface tendo ele. Na classe `Mundo`, o método `interpretar()` processará todos esses comandos.

Dessa forma, você não deverá ter muita dificuldade para acrescentar novos comandos se for preciso e nem isso afetará outras classes que não a classe `Mundo`.

A leitura do conteúdo do arquivo é feita com o `Files.readAllLines​(new File(file).toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` que vai pegar o conteúdo do arquivo e devolver uma `List<String>` contendo todas as linhas. Não "coma" o `IOException` resultante e prossiga como se nada tivesse ocorrido.

A sua pergunta é mais ou menos um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). O seu problema real (X) é como transformar esse arquivo em um mundo, e é isso que respondi aqui. O problema que você apresentou (Y) é sobre ler o conteúdo do arquivo e colocar em `LinkedList`, mas o que você quer é muito mais que isso.

Comment: Eu realmente gostei muito dessa resposta, Vou tentar aplicar, eu modifiquei a pergunta, porque achei que ninguém estava entendendo. Mas vou tentar aplicar o que você respondeu. Obrigado

Comment: @Matheus Excelente. Fico feliz em ter ajudado. Acabei de dar uma editada na resposta para simplificar um pouquinho.

Answer (score 0):

Isso daqui é mais ou menos um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). O seu problema real (X) é como transformar esse arquivo em um mundo [**e foi isso que eu respondi na outra resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277398/132).

Entretanto, se por algum motivo você só quiser a resposta do problema que você apresentou (Y), que é como colocar isso tudo numa `LinkedList`, seria isso:

```
try {
    List<String[]> lista = new LinkedList<>();
    Files.readAllLines​(new File(file).toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .stream()
            .map(s -> s.split(" "))
            .forEach(lista::add);
    return lista;
} catch (IOException e) {
     // ...
}
```

Deixando a exceção de lado e supondo que basta retornar uma lista, ao invés de ter que ser especificamente uma `LinkedList`:

```
return Files.readAllLines​(new File(file).toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .stream()
        .map(s -> s.split(" "));
```